# Android - Calling methods from notification action button

Tags: android, android-layout, android-notifications, action-button

I know that you can launch Activities from the action buttons using PendingIntents. How do you make it so that the a method gets called when the user clicks the notification action button?

```
public static void createNotif(Context context){
    ...
    drivingNotifBldr = (NotificationCompat.Builder) new NotificationCompat.Builder(context)
            .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.steeringwheel)
            .setContentTitle("NoTextZone")
            .setContentText("Driving mode it ON!")
            //Using this action button I would like to call logTest
            .addAction(R.drawable.smallmanwalking, "Turn OFF driving mode", null)
            .setOngoing(true);
    ...
}

public static void logTest(){
    Log.d("Action Button", "Action Button Worked!");
}
```

Answer (score 67, accepted):

You can't directly call methods when you click action buttons.

You have to use PendingIntent with BroadcastReceiver or Service to perform this. Here is an example of PendingIntent with BroadcastReciever.

**First lets build a Notification**

```
public static void createNotif(Context context){

    ...
    //This is the intent of PendingIntent
    Intent intentAction = new Intent(context,ActionReceiver.class);

    //This is optional if you have more than one buttons and want to differentiate between two
    intentAction.putExtra("action","actionName");

    pIntentlogin = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(context,1,intentAction,PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);
    drivingNotifBldr = (NotificationCompat.Builder) new NotificationCompat.Builder(context)
            .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.steeringwheel)
            .setContentTitle("NoTextZone")
            .setContentText("Driving mode it ON!")
            //Using this action button I would like to call logTest
            .addAction(R.drawable.smallmanwalking, "Turn OFF driving mode", pIntentlogin)
            .setOngoing(true);
    ...

}
```

**Now the receiver which will receive this Intent**

```
public class ActionReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {

    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {

        //Toast.makeText(context,"recieved",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

        String action=intent.getStringExtra("action");
        if(action.equals("action1")){
            performAction1();
        }
        else if(action.equals("action2")){
            performAction2();

        }
        //This is used to close the notification tray
        Intent it = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_CLOSE_SYSTEM_DIALOGS);
        context.sendBroadcast(it);
    }

    public void performAction1(){

    }

    public void performAction2(){

    }

}
```

**Declare Broadcast Receiver in Manifest**

```
<receiver android:name=".ActionReceiver" />
```

Hope it helps.

Comment: Thank you, this makes a lot of sense. However, I'm a little confused as to why you passed `intentAction` into `addAction`. Would it be `pIntentlogin`?

Comment: Updated. My bad! :)

Comment: Thank you so much!

Comment: This should be the tutorial on Android Developers Guide.

Comment: This is an excellent answer, but one part needs a warning; adding an extra to the intent will cause confusion further down the road:
"A common mistake: create multiple PendingIntent objects with Intents that only vary in their "extra" contents, expecting to get a different PendingIntent each time.  This does <em>not</em> happen. If you use two Intent objects that are equivalent as per {@link Intent#filterEquals(Intent) Intent.filterEquals}, then you will get the same PendingIntent for both of them.
There are two typical ways to deal with this..."

Comment: How can I access the `this` object of the `createNotif` method from the broadcast receiver?

Comment: Moslty you'll be using firebaseExtender, which will have getBaseContext() @DonaldDuck