# Calling functions instead of pendingIntent at notification addAction

Tags: java, android, android-notifications

currently I'm trying manage my button at notification bar, but I'm unable to call functions using `addAction`, because I must call a pendingIntent, not a function. Check my code below:

**MainActivity.java**

```
Notification.MediaStyle style = new Notification.MediaStyle();

    Bitmap notificationLargeIconBitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(this.getResources(), R.drawable.ic_play_circle_filled_black_24dp);

    Intent intent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), MainActivity.class);
    intent.setAction(intent.ACTION_MEDIA_BUTTON);
    PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getService(getApplicationContext(), 1, intent, 0);
         Notification.Builder builder = new Notification.Builder(this)
                .setVisibility(Notification.VISIBILITY_PUBLIC)
                 .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.ic_play_circle_outline_black_40dp)
                 .setLargeIcon(notificationLargeIconBitmap)
                 .setContentTitle(title)
                 .setContentText(author)
                 .setDeleteIntent(pendingIntent)
                 .setColor(this.getResources().getColor(R.color.colorPrimary))
                 .setPriority(Notification.PRIORITY_MAX)

                 .addAction(R.drawable.ic_skip_previous_black_24dp, "Prev", pendingIntent)
                 .addAction(R.drawable.ic_pause_black_24dp, "PlayOrPause", pendingIntent)
                 .addAction(R.drawable.ic_skip_next_black_24dp, "Next", pendingIntent)

                 .setStyle(style);
    notificationManager.notify(0, builder.build());
```

Please, note `.addAction(R.drawable.ic_pause_black_24dp, "PlayOrPause", pendingIntent)`, instead pendingIntent, is possible call `playorpause()` without errors? If I try it, I'll get `error: cannot find symbol variable playorpause`

Can you help me? Thank you.

Comment: It must be a `PendingIntent`. That's pretty much the only answer.

Comment: No no, I don't want call a PendingIntent, I want call a function instead. Is this possible?

Comment: It must be a `PendingIntent`.

Comment: Is there an trick to call a function across the pendingIntent?

Comment: Not a trick, really. You just have to accept that a `PendingIntent` can really only be used for an `Activity`, a `BroadcastReceiver`, or a `Service`. After that, you can call whichever method you want.

Comment: You can use a broadcast receiver in a notification and then in onReceive() execute whatever you wanted to do in a function.

Comment: I really don't know how do this, but I'm trying handle Indent. Please, check this: http://prntscr.com/l0dap0 and http://prntscr.com/l0datj

Comment: Do you know why isn't working? No errors

Comment: Your `Intent` is targeting `MainActivity` – presumably, an `Activity` subclass – but you're creating the `PendingIntent` with `getService()`, which is used with `Service`s. If you want to target an `Activity`, use `getActivity()`. Otherwise, change the `Intent` to target the appropriate `Service`.

Comment: I tried, but still not working, so I'm trying using BroadcastReceiver, check the current code: http://prntscr.com/l0dh9d and http://prntscr.com/l0dhg7, but still not working too... no errors, I don't know what I'm doing wrong :(

Comment: Also, I set this line at manifest > `<receiver android:name=".ActionReceiver" />`

Comment: The `Intent` is still targeting `MainActivity`.

Comment: I don't undestand, I'm following this > https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41312669/android-calling-methods-from-notification-action-button

Comment: Shouldn't be MainActivity? I if replace it to `ActionReceiver.class`, the app crash

Comment: Why would it be `MainActivity`? You're creating the PendingIntent with  `getBroadcast()`. Don't you want `ActionReceiver` to run? If so, then `ActionReceiver.class` is what you want. If it's crashing, then you'll need to look at [the stack trace](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23353173) to determine the cause of the crash. I suspect you're getting an `Exception` in the Receiver; likely a `NullPointerException`. If so, then the `PendingIntent` is working. You just need to fix the code in `ActionReceiver`.